# firefox user agent switcher does not go back to normal

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, mobile-url

I installed the user agent switcher add-on to my Firefox. Once I set a mobile browser and since then, for a news site automatically the m.newssite.com version comes in. Even when I set the user agent back to Firefox. Is it possible that not my browser but the web server of the newssite remembers my ip as a mobile device? How can I get back the normal version of the site?

Answer (score 0):

The site probably set a cookie. Go to `Firefox > Options > Privacy > Show cookies` Then look through the list for cookies from `*.newssite.com` and remove them. You will have to re-customize any preferences for that site, but it should default you back to the non-mobile site.